# Is there a way to show the hide column buttons in multiple columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, toggle

I have been using a hide column button [as shown here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/columns.html).

Notice upon clicking the "column visibility" button, it then shows a single column of buttons that represent which columns that can be hidden.

**What I would like to know is if there is a way to instead show multiple columns.**

The current plugin will list all the "column buttons" in a single column.  So if the table has, say 50 columns, it will show all 50 of the "column buttons" in a single column.  That could mean the user may have to scroll down the page to find the column they wish to hide.

I figure if they were a way to show multiple columns, the user would not have to scroll the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That library has a lot of useful documentation. I would start your search here: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/layout.html

Try adding the following code to your config:

```
buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'colvis',
                collectionLayout: 'fixed two-column'
            }
        ]
```

Next time if you post your code it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Nice.  When applying the text "fixed", it moved the toggle to the middle of the screen.  I didn't really need that.  Once I removed the text, the toggle went back to it's original position.  Thank you.

Comment: I wasn't sure if there was even a way to do this, which is why I didn't post any code.